# segmentation fault in cppunit at cleanup time

Tags: c++, cppunit

CPPUNIT crashes after execution of my program while returning from main during the cleanup phase. TestWrapping's dtor calls TestSuite's dtor which then calls deleteContents which triggers the test cases cleanup.

What's weird is that the TestSuite's dtor gets called twice ?
This follows the successful execution of 6 test cases. Any idea on how this can be avoided ?

```
    Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000000045 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000045 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000001004f2d in CppUnit::TestSuite::~TestSuite (this=0x7fe7bc005820, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at TestSuite.cpp:18
#3  0x0000000001004ebd in CppUnit::TestSuite::deleteContents (this=0x7fe7bc001040) at TestSuite.cpp:28
#4  0x000000000100500d in CppUnit::TestSuite::~TestSuite (this=0x7fe7bc005820, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at TestSuite.cpp:18
#5  0x0000000001004c50 in CppUnit::TestRunner::WrappingSuite::~WrappingSuite (this=0x7fe7bc005820, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ../../include/cppunit/TestRunner.h:101
#6  0x000000000040b72a in main (argc=0, argv=0x7fff8198bf08) at /project/EAB3_EMC/BRF/lmcgupe/brf/build/../software/brfc_test/BrfcTestMain.cc:447


Code exercising this:
(from main)
    CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResult controller;
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResultCollector result;
    controller.addListener( &result );

    // Show a message as each test starts
    //
    CppUnit::BriefTestProgressListener listener;
    runner.eventManager().addListener(&listener);
    controller.addListener( &listener );

    // Specify XML output and inform the runner of this format
    //
    std::ofstream xmlout("test_result.xml");
    CppUnit::XmlOutputter* outputter = new CppUnit::XmlOutputter(
            &result, xmlout);
    runner.setOutputter(outputter);


    CppUnit::TextOutputter consoleOutputter(&result , std::cout);

    runner.addTest(CreateAlarmBackupSuite::suite());
    runner.run( controller );

from class CreateAlarmBackupSuite: public CppUnit::TestFixture

    static CppUnit::Test *suite()
    {

        // Create the Test Suite
        //
        CppUnit::TestSuite *suite = new CppUnit::TestSuite("CreateAlarmBackupSuite");

        // Add the test cases

        //Crt_Syst_07
        suite->addTest(new CppUnit::TestCaller<CreateAlarmBackupSuite>(
                       "07_Crt_ScheduledBackup_ScheduledSingleEvent_SystemDataBackup_Non_Successful_Create_Persistent_ManualDelNotClear",
                &CreateAlarmBackupSuite::Crt_ScheduledBackup_ScheduledSingleEvent_SystemDataBackup_Non_Successful_Create_Persistent_ManualDelNotClear));



        //Crt_Syst_09
        suite->addTest(new CppUnit::TestCaller<CreateAlarmBackupSuite>(
                "09_Crt_ScheduledBackup_ScheduledSingleEvent_SystemDataBackup_Non_Successful_Create_Transient_NoRetry",
                &CreateAlarmBackupSuite::Crt_ScheduledBackup_ScheduledSingleEvent_SystemDataBackup_Non_Successful_Create_Transient_NoRetry));

return suite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping your code isn't explicitly calling these objects' destructors, but is either calling `delete` on a pointer to them, or else they are going out of scope and the compiler is automatically calling their destructors.  Assuming you're not explicitly calling destructors.....

It would seem that your TestSuite object either does a `delete this` or else it contains a pointer to itself (or obtains a pointer to itself somehow within deleteContents()) and then calls `delete` on that pointer.  You haven't posted the source for your `TestSuite` class (and specifically its `deleteContents()` method), but that's my guess, not having seen the code.

Comment: The WrappingSuite class is handling the deletion and cleanup. I don't explicitely call the deletes. I simply use the cookbook method from cppunit web site where a static method builds the test cases into a suite which is then fed to the addTest runner method.

Comment: OK, then, I'm guessing you're creating your TestSuite as a local object rather than using `new`?  Or something along those lines?

Comment: I create it with a new, populate it with test cases and give that object to my runner with runner.addTest. After that is runs the test and don't explicitely make any deletion on it. It seems like it's inside CppUnit that it has problem with it. It just crashes.

Comment: @user1964017 - Can you post a stripped-down version of your own code that evokes this behavior?

Comment: After running valgrind on my program and solving the major leaks and invalid reads that were reported, the problem was solved. The symptoms that were reported originally were most likely side effects of the leaks and invalid reads. The problem was reported on a test program which was not monitored for leaks as strictly as other programs, hence justifying why it fell under the radar.

Comment: @user1964017 - Thanks for the update!  Since nobody has any rep invested in this question, and since it's unlikely to be of any help to future visitors, would you mind deleting the question?  Thanks!